# How to add colour shape to header on external pdf file with Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, pdfpages, shapes

I am working on a  scanned PDF document to add a rectangular shape on the header to hide header text on all pages of the entire document.  To incorporate the external PDF's I use the pdfpages package.  Does anyone here know if, and if yes, how it can be done?

I'm stumped, any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycbox}[1]{\tikz{\path[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (15cm,1cm);}}

\begin{document}
 \mycbox{red}

\includepdf[pages=-,picturecommand*={\put(400,680){\Huge Some text}}]{original.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The screenshot of the original pdf is :

[image]

And the required output should be:
[image]

The source pdf is [here](https://ia601407.us.archive.org/22/items/4.-inverse-trigonometry-functions/4.%20INVERSE%20TRIGONOMETRY%20FUNCTIONS.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `current page` Tikz node's anchors and `overlay` the page with a Tikz picture. I used two rectangles, red and white, like in the desired output.

Adjust the `yshift=` parameter as desired.

[image: header hidden]

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\mycbox}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \draw[#1,fill=#1] (current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north east);
 \draw[#2,fill=#2] ([yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-3cm]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,picturecommand*={ \mycbox{red}{white}}]{original.pdf}
\end{document}
```

---

Edited to add:

To keep the original border frame visible, you can shrink the overlaid rectangles slightly:

[image: header]

with

```
 \draw[#1,fill=#1] ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-1.45cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north east);
 \draw[#2,fill=#2] ([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-1.45cm,yshift=-3cm]current page.north east);
```

Comment: @ Cicada Thank you for your answer, Unfortunately it is working only on first page, I need all the pages.

Comment: `picturecommand*` does first page only; `picturecommand` does all pages. Note: in the original, the header is only on the first page. If the header is on only some pages, use multiple instances of `\includepdf` with appropriate `[pages=` ranges and no (or appropriate) `picturecommand*` command. Similarly, if the headers are different sizes on different pages.